# Using OneDrive for versioning of source code

Tags: vim, onedrive

I decided to do my application development in a OneDrive folder now.  It gets backed up to the cloud automatically and Microsoft give it to me as part of a family subscription.

Just recently I wanted to recover a file and OneDrive wasn't keeping version history.  After some browsing, I notice that it is keeping version history on my Excel files.  But not on files with mysterious extensions (currently editing WiX files with extension .wsx) that I edit using Vim.

It may or may not be versioned if I use Microsoft's Notepad, although I really don't care because I'm just not going to use Notepad to edit source code.  Someone else can tell me if it is indeed versioned if using Notepad.

Can I somehow get Microsoft OneDrive to keep version history of my source code files if I use Vim?

Comment: Don't rely on OneDrive for version control or you will regret it. Just use Git or any other VCS.

Comment: "Microsoft give it to me as part of a family subscription" until they decide not do that anymore.

Comment: "Someone else can tell me if it is indeed versioned if using Notepad." - Why should it and why don't you try yourself? After you're done, make sure to remove the BOM that Notepad silently inserts.

Comment: @Friedrich Sometimes it pays to be a bit lazy.

Comment: @svlasov Only doing amateur development for my personal requirements atm.  No need for professional version control.  My version control consists of (very occasionally) renaming source code files to reflect a new version and continuing on.  OneDrive backs them up automatically so the latest version is always present.  That's good enough, although ioccasionally it's nice to go back a couple of hours if I stuff up.  No big deal though, I'll get by without it.  If I start developing for others (at home) then I'll install professional version control at home.

Comment: @romainl I'm no fan of Microsoft.  Just yesterday they switched my desktop with a dummy from OneDrive after I checked the OneDrive settings and switched backing up the desktop to OFF.  But I pretty well have to use them, I have a lot of Excel scripts now written in VB and I can't throw it all away.

Comment: I fully agree with your comment on laziness. Good luck!